# Regarding ROS(Meta operating system for robots) software

Tags: ros

I am working on the simulation of care-o-bot technologies (beginner to ROS). I read the ROS documentation and found some two similar things i.e. RVIZ and GAZEBO. Would you please tell me the difference between them...

Comment: I got a reply from ROS mailing list...So i thinked to post the answer here

RVIZ is a data visualization tool whereas GAZEBO is the simulator link STAGE. Without running robots or any robots simulator we can't process the data or do any kind of simulation. :)

Comment: please post the link to that reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RViz is a visualization tool for data coming from the Navigation Stack.

Gazebo is a 3D Robot simulator

Answer (score 0):

Gaebo is a robot simulator.
Rviz on the other hand is a limited - though very useful- visualization tool. When I say limited I mean that it is *usually* one-way. The ROS application publish messages and these are visualized in Rviz

There can be *some* kind of interactivity in Rviz (I have implemented menus in them for example) but it is not fully interactive